# Sending email in Xamarin Forms project

Tags: plugins, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to use the Xamarin.Plugins.Messaging NuGet package to send emails from within my Xamrin Forms shared project but keep running into `Warning: Attempt to present X on Y whose view is not in the window hierarchy!` and nothing appears.

Is there something else that I have to set up?

```
private void SendEmail()
{
    var emailMessagner = CrossMessaging.Current.EmailMessenger;
    if (emailMessagner.CanSendEmail)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Can send mail");
        var email = new EmailMessageBuilder()
            .To("emailaddress@gmail.com")
            .Subject("Setting subject")
            .Body("Setting email body")
            .WithAttachment(_filePath, "text/html")
            .Build();
        emailMessagner.SendEmail(email);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cant send mail");
    }
}
```

It works on android (other than getting `Permission denied for attachment`), but I get `window not in hierarchy` error for iOS. I could write my own email sender that would make sure it's viewController is in the window hierarchy but I assumed this plugin handled that.

Comment: Could you post the complete error details/stacktrace? Also, you can find the source code for the Messaging plugin [here](https://github.com/cjlotz/Xamarin.Plugins) to debug it on your own

Comment: Are you trying this on a real device or the simulator (i.e the simulator will fail)

Comment: @SushiHangover Yep it's a real device.

Comment: @Prashant It's just a warning I'm getting `2016-07-28 13:08:59.437 EmailApp[5929:7988240] Warning: Attempt to present <MFMailComposeViewController: 0x1609c2e00> on <Xamarin_Forms_Platform_iOS_ModalWrapper: 0x15fde0740> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`. The app isn't crashing or anything. And I've looked around there, so far everything looks exactly the same as what I have.

Comment: @Shane I would *assume* calling a `MakeKeyAndVisible` would help/fix, but actually getting the top/active PresentedViewController would be the best way, either way the source needs changed: https://github.com/cjlotz/Xamarin.Plugins/blob/c267e82d41fdc7d6eac20e92e983b085ce8f691f/Messaging/Plugin.Messaging.iOSUnified/MessagingExtensions.cs#L24

Comment: The with Attachment works only on PCL. Are you sure its PCL, because I see a `Console.WriteLine`. Also since its related to View can explain the view and how you are triggering the email?

Comment: @Rohit He is using a `Xamarin.Forms` shared project.

Comment: @SushiHangover I can get the top viewcontroller but I'm not sure howto use that with the plugin.

Comment: "Sending HTML e-mail and adding e-mail attachments are only supported on some platforms. Use the IEmailTask.CanSendEmailAttachments and IEmailTask.CanSendEmailBodyAsHtml API's to test whether the feature is available for the platform in your PCL code." Source - https://github.com/cjlotz/Xamarin.Plugins/blob/c267e82d41fdc7d6eac20e92e983b085ce8f691f/Messaging/Details.md

Comment: @Rohit Right and its showing that it can send Attachments and as html.. The only problem was that the view wasn't the main top/active view and I wasn't sure how I could change that with using the plugin. So I instead I just wrote my own email methods, and it's working fine now.

Comment: Okay great :) If you can post the solution for others reference it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with my Xamarin Forms app. I was calling SendEmail() from a ContentPage which I loaded with PushModalAsync() in a PCL project. As far as I can tell, this doesn't work in any way, shape or form from a modal form.

My work-around was to add a public static Queue property to the calling form (the main form of my app in this case) and when I needed to send an email, I added it to the queue. Then I overrode OnAppearing() on my main page and looped through all of the emails in the queue whenever the main form came back into view. I put a note on my modal form telling the user that the email would be sent when the modal form was closed. Not perfect, but it works. If you can find a way around this for modal forms, that would be fantastic!

Mike